# How to pass data from parent to child in loop and child is bootstrap modal in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5, react-props

**Unable to pass props from parent to child component if parent is looping to render child, and child component is modal, it doesn't update the value with every different component(only the first value is showing)**

```
arr.map((data)=>{ return (<component1 data={data}/>)};
```

**Component1**

```
  import MainbodyComp2 from "./mainbodyComp2";
  export default function MainbodyComp1({ data }) {

 
   const [data1] = useState(data);
 
return (
<div className="card m-3  " style={style1}>
  <img
    src={data.imagepath}
    style={style2}
    className=" img-thumbnail card-img-top"
    alt="..."
  />

  <div className="card-body">
    <h5 className="card-title">{data.location}</h5>

    <h5>${data.rent}k</h5>
    <span className="container d-flex align-items-center p">
      <div>
        <a
          href="#"
          className="btn btn-success m-3"
          onClick={() => {
            alert("Sorry this functionality is not available yet");
          }}
        >
          Rent it Now
        </a>
      </div>
      <MainbodyComp2 data={data1} />
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}

**BootStrap Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

 

   export default function MainbodyComp2(props) {
   const [data] = useState(props);
   return (
  <div className="bg-light">
  <div
    className="modal fade"
    id="exampleModalToggle"
    aria-hidden="true"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel"
    tabIndex="-1"
  >
    <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">
            {data.data.propertyType}
      //this remains same for every component
          </h5>

          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn-close"
            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body container">
          <span className="d-flex justify-content-start">
            <ImLocation />
            &nbsp; {data.data.location}
          </span>

          {data.data.description}
          <br />
          {data.data.moveInDate}
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <h5>only for ${data.data.rent}k</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a
    className="btn btn-primary"
    data-bs-toggle="modal"
    href="#exampleModalToggle"
    role="button"
    onClick={(e) => {
      console.log("this is console check event", e.target);
    }}
  >
    <BsInfoCircleFill />
  </a>
</div>
```

);
}

***Whenever I try to open modal the above content remains the same for every element***

One possible solution that I found is to hide the bootstrap component and show when it is toggled, but why doesn't the above method work?

Is there any solution to the problem? Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Bootstrap is a component. So it should be `props.data.val`. Either use `BootstrapComp=(props)` with `props.data.val` or `BootstrapComp=({data})`

Comment: Thank you, but This is not the problem, data with first iteration is showing in bootstrap modal. when I click on different component it doesn't show me the corresponding data

Comment: Is data an object that is being mutated somewhere?

Comment: Data is object, and it is not mutated anywhere.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] where we can gather better context over what the code is doing?

Comment: let me clarify the scenario, I'm having an array of object on which I am looping and rendering the component, this component has a child component which is a bootstrap modal. Now when I try to click on different modals, I get the same result for every modal.  Everything is good except in the bootstrap component (which i guess Has something to do with modal behaviour).

Comment: @Drew Reese Sure Sir, I will do that

Comment: @KapilChauhan try doing `data={...data}`. If you see same values in every component, either they all are pointing to same reference of have same value. If after this change you see same values, try checking the data

Comment: Why are you storing the passed `data` prop in local component state in each component? This is a React anti-pattern. Just consume the prop values directly. Can you provide an example `data` value that is passed as a prop to these components?

Comment: `const [data] = useState(props);` or `const [data1] = useState(data);` is a BAD code. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Rajesh As you can see in component1, h5 tag I am printing something. It is ok there, but when I am printing same in Bootstrap Component it is giving me the same result for every component. Please see the code, I've updated it

Comment: Just FYI a lot of component libraries will only render a single DOM element for the modal as an optimization. Without a more complete [mcve] that includes the steps you are taking to reproduce any issues we can't really say what is being rendered, and why.

Comment: @DrewReese, You are right, the problem is with modal not updating, When I console props everything is fine and also, I checked this on the dummy component, it worked fine but this modal component is not updating. Is there any way to refresh this modal component.

Comment: Thank you guys my issue has been solved, It was with modal ID which I was keeping the same for every component.  I'm just a beginner so I'm sorry to waste your precious time. Please have a look at the project that I created, https://630630fd0aa699075dcaf30b--jovial-druid-c36503.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

You have to destructure the data before using it in your component..

```
import Bootstrap from "abc/csf.js"
export default Component1=({data})=>{
 return(<div>
     // or use it as props.data.val
      {data.val}
      <Bootstrap data={data}/>
     </div>)
 }
```